# recursive mapping in python

Tags: python, recursion

What is the most pythonic way to apply a recursive function to structured/nested lists/list comprehension and return a structured/nested list/list comprehension of the same structure?

A minimal working example:

```
list1 = [[[1,2,3],[2,3,5],[5,2,2]], [[1,2],[3,1],[3,4]], [[2,3,4]]
list2 = [[[3,2,4],[2,1,1],[2,2,2]],[[3,3],[2,2],[1,1]],[[2,2,2]]]
```

I need a recursive function that is robust to the the structure of `list1`, 
 `list2` and possibly more, and to the vanilla function `lambda x,y: x*y`. The desired result in this tiny example is:

```
result = [[[3,4,12],[4,3,5],[10,4,4]],[[3,6],[6,2],[3,4]],[[4,6,8]]]
```

Another example using `list1` and `list3` where `list3` is:

```
list3 = [[[3],[2],[2]],[[3],[2],[1]],[[2]]]
```

and the desired result is:

```
result = [[[3,6,9],[4,6,10],[10,4,5]], [[3,6],[6,2],[3,4]], [[4,6,8]]
```

Comment: So, you can always guarantee that `list1` and `list2` have the same structure?

Comment: Not necessarily, they can be of different structures depending on the function being applied, and sometimes there could one or multiple extra lists that serves as lists of "constants" that remain unchanged across structures...

Comment: Um, with your example 3, how can you know how to handle it? `lambda x:y x*y` does not give you elementwise multiplication like in R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to see a recursive solution to this, in case your lists can be arbitrarily nested, you may prefer something like:

```
>>> list1 = [[[1,2,3],[2,3,5],[5,2,2]], [[1,2],[3,1],[3,4]], [[2,3,4]]]
>>> list2 = [[[3,2,4],[2,1,1],[2,2,2]],[[3,3],[2,2],[1,1]],[[2,2,2]]]
>>> def parallel_apply(l1, l2, f):
...     if isinstance(l1, list) and isinstance(l2, list):
...         return [parallel_apply(x,y, f) for x,y in zip(l1,l2)]
...     elif not isinstance(l1, list) and not isinstance(l2, list):
...         return f(l1, l2)
...     else:
...         raise ValueError("Structures incompatible for parallel apply")
...
>>> parallel_apply(list1, list2, lambda x,y: x*y)
[[[3, 4, 12], [4, 3, 5], [10, 4, 4]], [[3, 6], [6, 2], [3, 4]], [[4, 6, 8]]]
```

Note, Python has a maximum recursion depth and no tail-call optimization. If your lists can be nested *very deep* then you may have to transform this into an iterative solution.

Comment: @shenglih note, this will not handel the case where you have `list3`. It becomes a bit more complicated, but essentially, I think this give you an idea of the basic approach which you can extend to deal with your special cases.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this with [zip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) built-in function and [list comprehension](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk)

```
result = [[[x*y for x,y in zip(c,d)]for c,d in zip(a,b)] for a,b in zip(list1,list2)]
```

output:

```
[[[3, 4, 12], [4, 3, 5], [10, 4, 4]], [[3, 6], [6, 2], [3, 4]], [[4, 6, 8]]]
```

explanation:

what you're actually doing is that first, you're getting the two first lists of both `list1` and `list2`:

```
[[1,2,3],[2,3,5],[5,2,2]]
[[3,2,4],[2,1,1],[2,2,2]]
```

then in these lists access in the same way to :

```
[1,2,3]
[3,2,4]
```

then to :

```
1
3
```

then simply applying `x*y` to them and so on for all the data.

Hope this was helpful.